# Haar measure on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\lambda$ be the Haar measure on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$. What is the value of $\lambda(\{(0,0,...)\})$?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the Lebesgue measure on a set which isn't a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$? (Perhaps you mean the Lebesgue measure induced after some bijection with $\mathbb{R}$ or $[0,1]$ or something?)

Comment: Right, the set $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set...

Comment: I don't get you: $(0,0,\dots)$ is represented by a single point through the homeomorphism that you mention; what is the Lebesgue measure of a single point?

Comment: @AlexM. Of course none of this is _literally_ about _Lebesgue_ measure. The homeomorphism that's been mentioned is with the Cantor set, which has Lebesgue measure zero, but $\lambda$ of the set of all those sequences is $1$. (The relevant measure on the Cantor set is not Lebesgue measure...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I have attempted a Hausdorff measure-theoretic approach below. Since this subject is quite rusty for me, I hope I haven't gone astray with it.

Comment: Deleting my answer and nominating for reopening based on the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a *finite* sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s let $E_\alpha$ be the set of all sequences in $\Omega = \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ that *start* with $\alpha$.

Say $|\alpha|$ is the length of $\alpha$, so for example $|(1,0,1)|=3$.

Now if $|\alpha'|=|\alpha|$ then symmetry (or more formally the translation-invariance of $\lambda$) shows that $\lambda(E_\alpha)=\lambda(E_{\alpha'})$. Also the two sets are disjoint, and the union of the $E_\alpha$ over all $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=n$ is $\Omega$. So $$\sum_{|\alpha|=n}\lambda(E_\alpha)=1,$$and hence $$\lambda(E_\alpha)=2^{-|\alpha|}.$$

Now $$\{(0,0,0,\dots)\}=E_{(0)}\cap E_{(0,0)}\cap\dots,$$so that set has measure $0$.

That's measure theory. The same argument in probabilistic language: Say $X_1,\dots$ are iid random variables with $P(X_1=0)=P(X_1=1)=1/2$. Then $P(X_1=0,\dots ,X_n=0)=2^{-n}$, so $P(X_1=0,\dots)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

[The Cantor set has Hausdorff dimension $\frac {\log 2} {\log 3}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Self-similarity), which means that it can be naturally endowed with the $\frac {\log 2} {\log 3}$-[Hausdorff measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure). Since a point in it has Hausdorff measure $0$, its measure is necessarily $0$.

Comment: More or less; there are a few details to clean up. (i) your "which means that" is slight overstatement; in fact we need to know that $0<h_d(C)<\infty$ (where $C$ is the Cantor set and $d=\log(2)/\log(3)$), which is a stronger statement than just saying the hausdorff dimension is $d$. It's true, and presumably proved at the link you cite. (ii) We also need to show that the measure on $C$ induced by $\lambda$ is in fact (a multiple of) $h_d$. That's also true. And of course it's impossible to _prove_ it with things as stated, since there's been no actual _definition_ of $\lambda$.

Comment: Of course (ii) applies to my answer as well. I got around that by just assuming that $\lambda$ has certain symmetry properties; in the notation I used one could regard $\lambda(E_\alpha)=2^{-|\alpha|}$ as more or less the definition of $\lambda$. Or one could actually _define_ $\lambda$ by noting that $\Omega$ is a compact abelian group and saying $\lambda$ is Haar measure. (Both of which seem simpler than worrying about hausdorff measure.) Or one could show directly that there exists a measure $\lambda'$ on $C$ such that $\lambda'(C\cap[0,1/3])=1/2$, etc.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: In my answer I have (abusively?) assumed that the OP has misused the name "Lebesgue measure" in the question. I use a Hausdorff measure in my answer, you use a Haar one (in disguise) in yours. In any case, I don't get point (ii) of your comment: it is true only in integer Hausdorff dimension, since I don't see how to "induce" a Lebesgue measure in non-integer dimension (there is no pull-back for measures, only push-forward, and that is not useful here).

Comment: Yes, the OP certainly misued the term "Lebesgue measure". I don't get what you don't get about (ii). A measure certainly does have a pull-back with respect to a _bijection. In any case, we could just say I was thinking about the push--forward of the measure $\lambda$ on $\Omega$ (where $\Omega$ is that product). Regarding Haar versus Hausdorff: I didn't say what you said was _wrong_. But thinking of it as a Haar measure makes more sense to me, because it's more _intrinsic_ to the problem. The orignal problem had to do with $\Omega$. What is the hausorff dimension of $\Omega$? [continued]

Comment: The question of the hausdorff dimension of $\Omega$ is meaningless, because $\Omega$ is not a metric space. For any $d\in[0,\infty]$ there is a metric on $\Omega$, giving the same topology, that gives $\Omega$ hausdorff dimension $d$. And there are certainly metrics such that there does not exist $d$ with $0<h_d(\Omega)<\infty$. More concretely, there is a subset of $R$ homeomorphic to $C$ with any hausdorff dimension between $0$ and $1$. The only reason $\log(2)/\log(3)$ comes up is because of the particular Cantor set we choose.

Comment: Otoh, any compact-abelian-group isomorphism takes Haar measure to Haar measure, period. (Which is to explain what I mean by saying that Haar measure seem more "intrinsic".)